# What is the Security risk behind allowing a user to upload an HTML file to a Web Server?

Tags: html, security, iis, file-upload

Is there any security risk in allowing a user to upload an HTML file to our webserver?

Here are a few items to consider:

- Only the user can access their html files
- The file can contain javascript (if referenced from a different server)
- The HTML file is stored as binary data in the database until the user requests the document

I am more concerned about risks to the system, not so much to the user, since it would have to have been them who uploaded the file (or someone else who already has access to their account).

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty minimal if any. It's HTML so you're not executing anything on the server. If it's absolutely, positively only viewed by the uploader then there's no XSS or CSRF attack vectors of any value.

Your biggest risk is probably in the upload function and ensuring there's no malicious payload that could execute on the server side.

Comment: Those were my thoughts as well.  Thanks!

Comment: In particular, you need to protect the upload feature from (1) path traversal, in case files are written to a temporary location prior to being loaded into the DB (2) Denial of service by resource exhaustion (3) file extension in case it can be controlled by the uploader. You do not want the HTTP server to serve the uploaded file as asp, jsp, php, etc...

Comment: If the uploaded HTML is displayed in an `<iframe>` it could access the user's current "session" (e.g. cookies) in order to make API calls on behalf of the user. E.g. malicious things could happen. This can be mitigated by setting the `sandbox` attribute appropriately on the `<iframe>`.